# Authenticate Twitter users in a create-react-app frontend with .Net Core 5 REST API backend

Tags: c#, reactjs

This is my first Stack overflow question.  I am learning React and .Net Core 5.  I am working on an unfunded hobby project and want to allow potential users to be able to login with Twitter authentication before they are permitted to make updates in the backend database.

The frontend is a React project created with create-react-app.  This connects to a separate C# .Net Core 5 REST API project which accesses the SQL Server database.

[architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBDbk.png)

.Net Core 5 has inbuilt social media authentication - I could easily be wrong and don't know much about it, but this appears to be baked in to the MVC pipeline.  I do have the Consumer Key and App setup in Twitter.

I've looked but I just can't find a simple example of code do this.  Any relevant example code would be welcome.

Note: this is not for twitter app approval code but for many individual twitter users authentication.

Comment: see if this book [pro-asp.net-core-identity](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-identity) help

Comment: Thanks @lei-yang, I'll spend a day or two next week reading through this to understand what I need to do to implement the authentication process.